# Should i delete dist folder of my project made in netbeans?

Tags: java, netbeans

I am creating a project and day by day its size is increasing in GBs. It is normal DB Project consisting of cool GUI and some jar files. You will wonder to know that its size is now 1.34Gbs. [image]

I found a folder named dist , which is occupying 1.23GBs.
[image]

My question is that, should i delete this dist folder, or is it has any major role in my project.

The dist folder is containing these files,
[image]

Is there any way to decrease my project's space??

Comment: Yes, you can safely delete your dist folder; the reason being only those files are present inside it which are an outcome of a clean and build / rebuild - jar, war, jnlp, etc. **Though it's strange to see so many runXYZ folders**!

Comment: What kind of project is it? I guess it is a NetBeans/Ant project, right? As @Am_I_Helpful already mentioned the dist folder in that case is the outcome of your project, the compiled sources. I guess the runXYZ folders containing files of a file based database like derby or H2 and it is recreated everytime you start your application. If you run „Clean Build“ from the projects context menu the dist folder should be deleted and recreated, so the huge files should be gone.

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful Thanks for your help. It helped me a lot. Now i will delete that folder.Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

These are the files which are created by "build" option in NetBeans. That means these are cross platform executable versions of your project. Deleting them won't do any harm to your source files.

Answer (score 1):

The dist folder will be created once you click the **build** function in the Netbeans IDE. The dist folder is the executable project folder, it will not affect your project if you want to delete it.

Remember, even you delete you dist folder, it IDE will create a new one whenever you click **build** the project again.

TIPs: try to use **clean build** to build the project since it will automatically remove the older builds and only saves the newest build version.

Comment: Thanks @Minwu Yu for your help. But still i have a query that i always press clean and built button, then why it doesnot remove my old build versions?

Comment: I guess you need to check your query for that command. Make sure you are doing "clean and build" but not "build". If it is "clean and build", that means those files were not older version files but the current project files. And the reason why the project will have so much runxxxx folders, it's probably somewhere your codes generated these.

Answer (score 1):

Your project should contains just your source code and resources that affect the behavior of your app. Those files that are created by your IDE must not affect this configuration.

If you are currently working with this project I don't recommend you to delete them, but if you configured correctly your project through build automation tools (like maven, gradle, etc) it has no importance, because the IDE must be intelligent enough to read these configurations and set your entire project automatically.